# How to determine if an image file is georeferenced

Tags: c#, georeferencing, image

I have a task to scan a folder for georeferenced images. There might be a lot of images, some quite large, and some not georeferenced. The spatial information can also be either embedded or in a world file.

Programmatically (C#/WPF/ESRI Runtime) how can I tell if "C:\someFolder\file.x" is georeferenced.

Thanks

Comment: What format(s) are the images?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the gdalinfo tool which will do exactly what you want. You need to then pipe the output through a tool such as awk to interpret the results depending on what it is you want to know

[Gdal information here](http://www.gdal.org/)